# Delete superfluous line in longtables (LaTeX)

Tags: longtable, multirow, multicolumn, rowcolor

This is the first table I have:

```
\begin{longtable}{|p{4cm}|p{4cm}|}
\caption{Caption of the table}\\ \hline
\rowcolor{black} \textcolor{white}{\textbf{Column 1}} & \textcolor{white}{\textbf{Column 2}} \\\hline
Row 1\qquad\qquad  & AAA \qquad\qquad \\\hline
Row 2 & BBB \\\hline
Row 3 & CCC \\\hline
\label{ratings}
\end{longtable}
```

Unfortunately it looks like that:

[image]

And this is the second table which is similar:

```
\begin{longtable}[h]{|*{2}{>{\columncolor{black}\color{white}}c}*{7}{|c}|}
\caption{Caption of the table with Multirow and Multicolumn}\\
\cline{9-7}
\rowcolor{black}\multicolumn{2}{c|}{\cellcolor{white}{}} 
                     & \textcolor{white}{\textbf{Column 1}}    
                     & \textcolor{white}{\textbf{Column 2 }}            
                     & \textcolor{white}{\textbf{Column 3 }}           
                     & \textcolor{white}{\textbf{Column 4 }}
                                         & \textcolor{white}{\textbf{Column 5 }}                        \\ \hline
                     & \textbf{$\lambda_1$} \quad \textbf{$\lambda_2$} & 0,3 \quad 0,5 & 0,1 \quad 0,2 & 0,3 \quad 0,8 & 0,4 \quad 0,7 & 0,1 \quad 0,2 \\
                     & \textbf{$\tau$}           & 3             & 2             & 0,1           & 1             & 2  \\
\multirow{-3}{*}{\begin{minipage}{0.7in}
\begin{center}
\textbf{Row 1}
\end{center}
\end{minipage}} & \textbf{$\rho$}           & 1             & 0             & -5            & -2            & 1 \\ \hline
                                         & \textbf{$\lambda_1$} \quad \textbf{$\lambda_2$} & 0,3 \quad 0,5 & 0,1 \quad 0,2 & 4 \quad 2     & 0,1 \quad 0,2 & 0,1 \quad 0,2\\
                     & \textbf{$\tau$}           & 3             & 2             & 0,1           & 1             & 2\\
\multirow{-3}{*}{\begin{minipage}{0.7in}
\begin{center}
\textbf{Row 2}
\end{center}
\end{minipage}} & \textbf{$\rho$}           & 1             & 0             & -5            & -2            & 1 \\ \hline
\label{thisisthelabel}
\end{longtable}
```

That is what it looks like with the unnecessary last black line:

[image]

Can anyone help me deleting the last superfluous line that appears in both tables?

Comment: Put the label just after  the caption.

Comment: longtable does not have an `[h]` option.

Comment: @TeXnician: I don't think this is necessary, as there's a deleted (why?) answer, which is correct. Maybe someone can undelete it?

Comment: @TeXnician: I voted to undelete it. 30 votes are still required…

Comment: @Bernard Or one by a mod ;)

Answer (score 1):

You have to put the `\label` after the caption.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{longtable,multirow}
\begin{document}
  \begin{longtable}{|p{4cm}|p{4cm}|}
\caption{Caption of the table}\label{ratings}\\ \hline
\rowcolor{black} \textcolor{white}{\textbf{Column 1}} & \textcolor{white}{\textbf{Column 2}} \\\hline
Row 1\qquad\qquad  & AAA \qquad\qquad \\\hline
Row 2 & BBB \\\hline
Row 3 & CCC \\\hline
\end{longtable}

\begin{longtable}[h]{|*{2}{>{\columncolor{black}\color{white}}c}*{7}{|c}|}
\caption{Caption of the table with Multirow and Multicolumn}\label{thisisthelabel}\\
\cline{9-7}
\rowcolor{black}\multicolumn{2}{c|}{\cellcolor{white}{}}
                     & \textcolor{white}{\textbf{Column 1}}
                     & \textcolor{white}{\textbf{Column 2 }}
                     & \textcolor{white}{\textbf{Column 3 }}
                     & \textcolor{white}{\textbf{Column 4 }}
                                         & \textcolor{white}{\textbf{Column 5 }}                        \\ \hline
                     & \textbf{$\lambda_1$} \quad \textbf{$\lambda_2$} & 0,3 \quad 0,5 & 0,1 \quad 0,2 & 0,3 \quad 0,8 & 0,4 \quad 0,7 & 0,1 \quad 0,2 \\
                     & \textbf{$\tau$}           & 3             & 2             & 0,1           & 1             & 2  \\
\multirow{-3}{*}{\begin{minipage}{0.7in}
\begin{center}
\textbf{Row 1}
\end{center}
\end{minipage}} & \textbf{$\rho$}           & 1             & 0             & -5            & -2            & 1 \\ \hline
                                         & \textbf{$\lambda_1$} \quad \textbf{$\lambda_2$} & 0,3 \quad 0,5 & 0,1 \quad 0,2 & 4 \quad 2     & 0,1 \quad 0,2 & 0,1 \quad 0,2\\
                     & \textbf{$\tau$}           & 3             & 2             & 0,1           & 1             & 2\\
\multirow{-3}{*}{\begin{minipage}{0.7in}
\begin{center}
\textbf{Row 2}
\end{center}
\end{minipage}} & \textbf{$\rho$}           & 1             & 0             & -5            & -2            & 1 \\ \hline
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

[image]